# How to fetch array data from single column using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have data into my database like this way

Table: product

```
product_ID   | product_qty

  1          |  50

  2          |   30

  3          |   40
```

I want to fetch product_qty values from product table where product_ID (1,2,3)are in array form using codeigniter.

**My_Controller.php**

```
    public function addMTStore_post(){
    $userdata = array();
    $userdata['product_ID']= $this->post('product_ID');

        for ($i=0;$i<count($userdata['product_ID']);$i++){
          $value = array( "product_ID" =>$userdata["product_ID"][$i]
                          );
         $product_quantity = $this->move_To_Store->getQty($userdata['product_ID']);
        return product_quantity ;
    }
         }
```

**move_To_Store.php**

```
public function getQty($product_ID = array()){

foreach($product_ID as $key){   
$this->db->select('total_product_quantity');
$this->db->from('product');
$this->db->where('product_ID',$product_ID);
$query = $this->db->get()->row()->total_product_quantity;
echo  $query ;
            }
      }
```

I want to display product_qty values using product_ID. But i am unable to fetch.
Please help me to find out solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: use $key in your where() clause

Comment: Just use `where_in` without foreach loops

Comment: Use This Query :    $this>db->query("Select column_name FROM table_name WHERE column_name=`value`");

Comment: Thanks. I got solution for it.

Comment: Try this to your Controller

<?php 
$data=array('1','2','3');

foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
 $d=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_ID='".$value."'");
 $result=$d->result_array();
 var_dump($result) // show data form Result as an array()
}
?>